# How to use cloudera management (ui) console to edit hadoop-metrics.properties?

Tags: hadoop, monitoring, hbase, cloudera, ganglia

I am trying to monitor Hbase using Ganglia. How to use cloudera management console to edit dfs.server property in the hadoop-metrics.properties?

According to 
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GangliaMetrics I need to change:

```
dfs.servers=@GANGLIA@:8649
```

But I am not able to see the option to modify dfs.server value on the management console of cloudera.

How should I proceed?

```
dfs.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics.ganglia.GangliaContext31
mapred.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics.ganglia.GangliaContext31
hbase.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics.ganglia.GangliaContext31
jvm.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics.ganglia.GangliaContext31
rpc.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics.ganglia.GangliaContext31
ugi.class=org.apache.hadoop.metrics.ganglia.GangliaContext31
dfs.period=10
mapred.period=10
hbase.period=10
jvm.period=10
rpc.period=10
ugi.period=10
dfs.fileName=/tmp/metrics/dfs.log
mapred.fileName=/tmp/metrics/dfs.log
hbase.fileName=/tmp/metrics/hbase.log
jvm.fileName=/tmp/metrics/jvm.log
rpc.fileName=/tmp/metrics/rpc.log
ugi.fileName=/tmp/metrics/ugi.lo
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Cloudera management console has ability to edit hadoop-metrics.properties configuration through UI instead, you just need to edit this configuration manually. In Hadoop hadoop-metrics.properties configuration settings contains settings for the metrics contexts "dfs", "mapred", and "jvm" so you can edit the "dfs" section as below:

First stop the HDFS service.

Visit conf/hadoop-metrics.properties add the changed you need for GangliaMetrics:

```
dfs.servers=@GANGLIA@:8649
```

Restart the HDFS service

Comment: The management console has the ability. You can click configuration tab to modify only some properties. The problem is that  hadoop-metrics.properties is auto-generated by scm and the metrics from the default location is not picked up. https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/group/scm-users/browse_thread/thread/75c91de18684d15e   Check   
Philip Zeyliger's response. I have the same issue